# Separate paragraphs not displaying on their own lines

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a stats area for a site. On desktop it should be two across and on mobile it should be stacked. It would be nice if the content of the very inner DIV was stacked but I can't figure out how to do this.

Desktop should look something like this
[image: Desktop Layout]

And mobile something like this
[image: Mobile layout]

Here's my code

```css
.site-stats-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: pink;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.site-stats-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background: pink;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}
}

.site-stats-group {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

.site-stat-title {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.site-stat-title {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
}

.site-stat-info {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.site-stat-info {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
}

.site-stat-title-display {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.site-stat-info-display {
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.site-stat-title {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 35px;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.site-stat-title {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
}
}

.site-stat-subtitle {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.site-stat-subtitle {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-size: 20px;
    line-height: normal;
    margin: 0;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="site-stats-wrap">
   <div class="site-stats-group">
      <div class="site-stat-title">
         <div class="site-stat-title-display">
             <p class="site-stats-title">Statistics</p>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="site-stat-info">
         <div class="site-stat-info-display">
            <p class="site-stat-title">Title</p>
            <p class="site-stat-subtitle">A Short Description</p>
            <br>
            <p class="site-stat-title">Title</p>
            <p class="site-stat-subtitle">A Short Description</p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

The problems I'm facing now are
A) The contents of each column isn't centered (they'd just take their height on mobile based on their contents but need to be the same height on desktop within the wrapper)
B) Text within the stats section doesn't appear on its own line.

Any answers that center the contents and help with the text issue would be appreciated.

`UPDATE`
Based on [Andrew Halpern](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7196605/andrew-halpern)'s answer.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: pink;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  text-align: center;
}

.col1 {
  width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col1 {
  width: 100%;
}
}

.col2 {
  width: 50%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
.col2 {
  width: 100%;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col1">
    <h1>I'm Centered</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <h1>I'm Centered Too</h1>
    <h1>I'm Centered Too</h1>
    <h1>I'm Centered Too</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, but this code won't bring you anywhere. It would be too much to explain every detail, but in general you can much easier do this kind of stuff using CSS flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: The code is functional though. An answer with a different approach is helpful.

Comment: I would use CSS grid and flexbox for this problem. It will make responsiveness easier as well as the code cleaner.

Comment: I've been trying with this for a while @JasonB95. Care to post an answer?

Answer (score 0):

Here's that code rewritten using Flexbox, it should achieve the behavior you want.

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: pink;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.col1,
.col2 {
  padding: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col1">
    <h1>I'm Centered</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <h1>I'm Centered Too</h1>
    <h1>I'm Centered Too</h1>
    <h1>I'm Centered Too</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It's really really close. The contents just aren't horizontally centered. I've been trying to figure this out for so long. I just need 50% width on desktop and 100% on mobile. The problem is the lack of horizontal centering and the padding but I could remove that.

Comment: If you take a look at my updated question, would that work the same?

Comment: I'm not sure what the difference is here? The styling of col2 is incorrect?

Comment: The padding means that on mobile the columns are too big. I've just set widths for the columns in separate classes for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't apply a normal size text-center. I only applied it in mobile sizes. I guess this is what you want.

```css
 .site-stats-group {
      background: pink;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-evenly;
      align-items: center;
      font-size: 2rem;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
        .site-stats-group {
          flex-direction: column;
        }
        .site-stat-info {
          text-align: center;
        }
    }
```

```html
<div class="site-stats-wrap">
    <div class="site-stats-group">
      <div class="site-stat-title">
        <div class="site-stat-title-display">
          <p class="site-stats-title">Statistics</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="site-stat-info">
        <div class="site-stat-info-display">
          <p class="site-stat-title">Title</p>
          <p class="site-stat-subtitle">A Short Description</p>
        </div>
        <div class="site-stat-info-display">
          <p class="site-stat-title">Title</p>
          <p class="site-stat-subtitle">A Short Description</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Close but the contents of the columns shouldn't dictate their size. They should always be 50% on desktop and then within that 50% column the content should be centered

Answer (score 0):

The CSS:

```
.container {
                width: 50%;
                margin: 0 auto;
                display: grid;
                grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
            }

            .left-side,
            .right-side {
                padding: 2rem;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }

            .left-side {
                background-color: crimson;
            }

            .right-side {
                background-color: cornflowerblue;
            }

            @media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
                .container {
                    width: 100%;
                    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
                }
            }
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="left-side">
            <h1>Centered.</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
            <div class="items">
                <h1>Centered.</h1>
                <h1>Centered.</h1>
                <h1>Centered.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image: Desktop View]
[image: View when screen size reduces to 768px or under]

Answer (score 0):

Use flex and change the `flex-direction` to `column` in the media query for smaller screens:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  background: pink;
  align-items: center;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.col1,
.col2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  .wrap {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .col1,
  .col2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="col1">
    <h1>I'm Centered</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="col2">
    <h1>I'm Centered Too</h1>
    <h1>I'm Centered Too</h1>
    <h1>I'm Centered Too</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```